# javascript function that is called once and then reset according to a boolean state

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Im looking for a function that is called once and is then rearmed according to a boolean state.

After some hacking around I found Pauls answer below was an effective way of executing / rearming a function inside the draw loop.

However I have found while incorporating this code with a class with more than one instance inside a for loop the function is being triggered and reset multiple times per instance. as per my example code below.

```
let instances = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    instances.push(new Ball(50, random(30,370)));
  }
}

const [happenOnce, reset] = makeRunOnce(() => {
  console.log("ball has crossed the line!");
});

function makeRunOnce(fn) {
  let hasRun = false;
  return [
    // run
    () => {
      if (!hasRun) {
        fn();
        hasRun = true;
      }
    },
    // reset
    () => {
      hasRun = false;
    }
  ]
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  line(200, 0, 200, height);
  
  for (let i = 0; i < instances.length; i++) {
    instances[i].showBall();
    instances[i].moveBall();
    
    if(instances[i].returnTrue()) {
      happenOnce();
    } else {
      reset();
    }
  }
}

class Ball{
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y
    this.r = 10;
    this.t = random();
  }
  
  showBall() {
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.r * 2);
  }
  
  moveBall() {
    this.x += this.t;
  }
  
  returnTrue() {
    return this.x + this.r > 200;
  }
}
```

Anyone have any suggestions on how I can have the function execute once when the class method returns true and resets when false for every instance?

Comment: When do you want the functions to "re-arm"? Is there a timeout shared by all, or is it dependent on each audio file's duration, or something else?

Comment: You could use something like lodash's [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce) or [throttle](https://lodash.com/docs#throttle)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I would like the function to "re-arm" when the boolean value is false as per the first code example. Because of the generative nature of code there is no fixed time to which the boolean value will remain true before switching back to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you might be over complicating things a little bit, but all you need here is the ability to reset that `executed` flag back to false. Here is an example with a helper function `makeRunOnce` which takes a function and returns two functions in an array. The first function runs the original function only the first time it is called (either initially or after a reset), and the second function resets the state back to uncalled. To test this example, clicking draws a circle the first time you click, additional clicks will be ignored, until you double click which resets the state such that the next click will draw another circle.

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

const [drawCircleOnce, resetDrawCircle] = makeRunOnce(() => {
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
});

let mouseHasBeenClicked = false;

function draw() {
  if (mouseHasBeenClicked) {
    drawCircleOnce();
  } else {
    resetDrawCircle();
  }
}

// Note: instead of setting the mouseHasBeenClicked flag here
// we could just call drawCircleOnce() directly, and then
// resetDrawCircle() in doubleClicked. The draw() function would
// then be a no-op. I've use this flag to more closely 
// approximate the apparent structure of your code.
function mouseClicked() {
  mouseHasBeenClicked = true;
}

function doubleClicked() {
  // reset
  mouseHasBeenClicked = false;
}

function makeRunOnce(fn) {
  let hasRun = false;
  return [
    // run
    () => {
      if (!hasRun) {
        fn();
        hasRun = true;
      }
    },
    // reset
    () => {
      hasRun = false;
    }
  ]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Plenty to unpack here, I haven't seen alot of this syntax before. I shall hack around and see how I get on. will let you know how I get on. Thanks once more @Paul Wheeler